# Spread SQL Server tempdb files across a lun

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have read quite a bit about spreading tempdb and database files across luns to optimize sql server, my question is if I have just one LUN, would spreading the tempdb have any positive effect or it is better to request for additional separate disk to get performance benefits?

Answer (score 0):

Having more than one database file (no matter which database) on one single physical disk (LUN or not) does not provide improved performance most of the time.

Regarding tempdb, it will improve the performance if there is allocation contention. In that case you should create as many equally sized database files as the number of logical processors.

But if you can request more LUN's why to assign them to tempdb? Is tempdb so overloaded? Typically you will get better overall performance if the new LUN's is assigned to other databases.

Comment: PFS page contention can be alleviated by creating multiple tempdb data files on the same LUN, assuming they are [created correctly](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/correctly-adding-data-files-tempdb/).

Comment: @Bryan Eargle. thanks for sharing. Sometimes I learn more answering than asking :-). I edited my answer.